# CKEditor Font Size and Family buttons does not appear

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I tried to install [CKEditor Font Size and Family](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_font) on my fresh Drupal 8 install, but both buttons does not seem to show up.

1. Plugin is placed in `/libraries`
2. `CKEditor` and `CKEditor Font` modules are both activated
3. Both buttons <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd> appear when I edit my content format (`Full HTML`)
4. Both buttons were added to the `Full HTML` CKEditor toolbar
5. My content use `Full HTML` format, and I am administrator
6. **But these buttons does not appear when I edit my content**

This problem is still here after a few days of development, so I'm already sure it's not cache-related.

Did I miss something in my configuration?
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunetally, no. I've been struggling with this for hours without success ; it works perfectly on the production server, and I cannot understand the difference with the dev server, so I gave up, sorry.

Comment: Is it possible that your "Allowed HTML tags" are not synced with the dev server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I put the center, left, and right align buttons in my "TOOLBAR CONFIGURATION".  But You also need to add the **class** attribute to the filter to "Allowed HTML tags" at the bottom of the page.

```
<p id class> <br> <u> <s> <em> <strong> <cite> <blockquote cite> <code> <ul class type> <ol class start type> <li class> <dl> <dt> <dd> <h2 id> <h3 id> <h4 id> <h5 id> <h6 id> <drupal-entity data-entity-type data-entity-uuid data-entity-embed-display data-entity-embed-display-settings data-align data-caption data-embed-button> <img src alt data-entity-type data-entity-uuid data-align data-caption> <a class href hreflang !href id rel target title> <table> <iframe src frameborder width height scrolling allowfullscreen> <caption> <tbody> <thead> <tfoot> <th> <td> <tr>
```

Comment: Nice catch! This indeed fix the issue, many thanks.